# Add touch screen support to tile navigation

Tags: movement, touch, godot

I saw this awesome tutorial that is related to [Grid-based Movement in Godot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtnnKVxoH5k)

What I want is to add touch screen support for this kind of movement i.e. with virtual on screen joystick or gestures.

How it can be done?

What is the best way to implement that so the user will have the easiest way of movement?

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? If you've already implemented the movement and only missing the touch input, you can always create some UI elements that trigger that kind of movement. Have you tried that?

Comment: @TomTsagk I'm looking for advice regarding the best way to do this kind of behavior on a touchscreen - I assume that it can be an on-screen button, a gesture slide or a virtual joystick. I want advice regarding what particular method is better for a scenario as in the tutorial - I think that virtual joystick but maybe I'm wrong. and another think I am looking is a way to implement it in Godot

Comment: All methods you described work. Unfortunately the format of this site is not well suited for giving advice, as there is no one correct answer, all of them could be equally correct. It's better to ask questions like "I want to do X, so far I've tried Y and Z and I'm stuck on this one step".